# How to get notification on the dashboard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have articles section in my application , and I want to show a flash notification on the dashboard for all the users who in my application if they are logged in or when they log in , when a user post a new article ?

How can I do so ? and I need an explain because I asked before and I didn't get any answers.

i need something like this !

[image]

Comment: There's a lot about flashes here in the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash).

Comment: i know the flash but i need to make a notification on the dashboard to all users who in my application either they logged in or when they log in !!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of flash messages, you seem to be looking for "One-off announcements" or "Side-wide annoucements".

Two great resources, all here listed [Plugingeek](http://www.plugingeek.com/categories/site-wide-announcements-ruby), might help you.

- [paul_revere](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paul_revere) by thoughtbot: *Simple announcement plugin to include "one off" style announcements in Rails web apps.*
- [Site-wide annoucements RailsCast (pro)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/103-site-wide-announcements-revised)

Comment: how can I use it for articles when a new one is posted ?

Comment: what is the different between both ??